# Scaling without losing value importance Python Sklearn

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

The sample of the csv is:

```
0.03528821669081923,0.4209514856338501
0.4755249949860231,0.4248427748680115
0.09710556840327728,0.4209169149398804
0.07149631133318766,0.4201127290725708
-0.2400341908399068,0.417565792798996
-0.17768551828033466,0.4184338748455048
-0.30025757809215714,0.416279673576355
-0.09094791496191304,0.41964152455329895
0.07154744586719554,0.4196658134460449
0.2381333126503035,0.42377570271492
0.2593105332145284,0.4222800433635712
-0.6691065606953182,0.4089060425758362
-0.6456401882265393,0.4092327654361725
-0.2320063391631248,0.4154394268989563
0.03676064944004283,0.4164957106113434
-0.049027521405378964,0.4175394177436829
-0.5611679536206179,0.4090659916400909
-1.151078217514793,0.3977192640304565
-1.1251183926252533,0.3976330757141113
-1.3598634565590335,0.3943647146224976
-1.452113101667516,0.3926326930522919
-1.724856436518542,0.3888352811336517
-1.3449567318568625,0.3950198888778687
-0.9327234868901516,0.39986416697502136
-0.8698905846258818,0.40163424611091614
-1.0829297248122909,0.4009062349796295
-0.7123502605778409,0.406065821647644
-0.7078240398708294,0.4043383300304413
-1.0054995188827682,0.4010890424251557
-0.40067943737923295,0.41085284948349
-0.3684788480142471,0.4130916893482208
-0.31293912846313354,0.4178936183452606
```

I have loaded it in pandas and tried to scale it with `sklearn.preprocessing.scale()` but it only does the scaling on the column specified.

```
df['col1'] = sklearn.preprocessing.scale(df['col1'].values)
df['col2'] = sklearn.preprocessing.scale(df['col2'].values)
```

I want to scale on column with respect to another, so that I can plot then on same figure. This is only possible if the values are some how in the same range and do not loose there value importance.
Please suggest me what I can do.

Comment: You might want to consider using `sklewarn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()` which by default will scale `col1` and `col2` to be in the range of `0-1` by default, although its possible to specify the `min` and `max` bounds of the range you are scaling to if you desire.

Comment: I tried that. But it is loosing the value importance.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is to instead use [`sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler), which can be fitted using an array, and then transform other arrays using the computed `mean` and `std`. So you could do as follows:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
```

Reshape the numpy arrays from the dataframe columns:

```
col1 = x['col1'].values.reshape(-1,1)
col2 = x['col2'].values.reshape(-1,1)
```

Fit the instanciated object using `col1`:

```
fitted = scaler.fit(col1)
```

Standardize all features using the `mean` and `std` from `col1`:

```
col1 = fitted.transform(col1)
col2 = fitted.transform(col2)
```

Comment: One question, why you reshape the column?

Comment: One more query, have you tried it? I get the same result as the real value.

Comment: Yes, will do in a sec I'm out. I reshaped it so it can be fed, otherwise it complains. Its the same for the MinMaxScaler.